# error while passing values to a class "DATABASEHAELPER" from a class "SERVER"

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

DATABASEHELPER Class code

```
public boolean insertData(String latitude,String longitude,String route){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1,latitude);
        contentValues.put(COL2,longitude);
        contentValues.put(COL3,route);
       long result= db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
       if(result==-1)
           return false;
        else
           return true;
    }
```

SERVER class code

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params)  {


        mydb.insertData("sffaju","aasju","ajsssu");
    }
```

can't pass value from insertData function

Comment: elaborate `can't pass value from insertData function`. Are there any errors or what?

Comment: i have tried to pass the string value from a class called "server" to the class called "Databasehelper" class which has the funtion insertData.

Comment: what error you are getting @jibin

Comment: Is `Server` a real server or is it just a *buzz word* you used to name a class in your app? It seems the latter. Well try this: `if(result < 1)` instead of `if(result==-1)`. Also, you need to start your AsyncTask, somewhere. It won't start automatically if noone tells it to start.

Comment: Server is not a real server.only a class name